# Run multiple function in sequence within a process using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

i'm a newbie on `multiprocessing`.

What I'm trying to achieve is to run multiple function in sequence within a process using multiprocessing.

Example:

I have 5 dataframes that needs to be inserted in a database in 5 separate tables.
Before Inserting I'd like to check that data format is correct, that the column order is correct, a brief check of data quality.
Let's suppose that I've wrote 4 functions, namely `correct_data_format()`, `column_order()` and `data_quality()`. Add also an `insert_db()` functions.

I'd like to run those 4 functions for each dataframe.

In my mind I should have 5 different process for each dataframe and each process should run in sequence the 4 functions mentioned above ( `correct_data_format()` -> `column_order` -> `data_quality` -> `insert_db`)

How to achieve that using `multiprocessing` package?

Comment: You could use multiprocessing.Pool, define a function that works on a dataframe and does all the checks you need and returns True/False, and use the Pool.map method

Comment: And If i din't want to wrap all functions into one? Is it possible to achieve what I described?

Comment: Pool.map doesn't work with lambda functions, so for that you'll have to define some function or class. Maybe there is a way I'm not aware of with some other api of multiprocessing

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have 5 dataframes df1, df2, df3, df4 and df5.
The following code will probably do what you want:

```
import multiprocessing

def func(df):
    correct_data_format(df)
    column_order(df)
    data_quality(df)
    insert_db(df)
    ...
    [some other stuff]

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
pool.map(func, (df1, df2, df3, df4, df5))
```